# How to be sure "Parity" is installed on Windows?

Tags: parity, ropsten, windows

I installed `Parity` after downloading and running `exe` file from here : https://www.parity.io/

However, when I use following command to connect to `Ropsten` as follows :

```
parity db kill --chain ropsten
```

I receive following error :

```
C:\Users\s>parity db kill --chain ropsten
'parity' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

What is missing ? and how can I connect to `Ropsten` ?

Note: **Operating System** is `Windows 8.1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first navigate to the right folder before being able to launch parity.exe. It is explained in the FAQ: https://wiki.parity.io/FAQ#how-to-launch-parity-ethereum-using-the-command-line-on-windows

1. Make sure you close Parity Ethereum and that no parity process is running (using Ctrl + Alt + Esc)
2. Navigate in Windows Explorer to the Parity Ethereum folder where parity.exe is, it should be located in C:\Program Files\Parity Technologies\Parity
3. Highlight the complete folder path in the top pane, type cmd and hit Enter
4. This opens a command line window in the Parity Ethereum folder, you can launch Parity Ethereum with CLI flags

Note that you should launch `parity.exe --chain ropsten` as the `db kill` would delete your database.